# Can't access external link with python + h5py

Tags: python, python-3.x, hdf5, h5py, hdf

Recently I have started working with `.hdf5` files and still can't figure out how to properly use external links.

I have got a few `.hdf5` files. Each file has got the same structure e.g. same keys and data types. I want to merge them into one file but keep them separate with a different key for each file.

Here's what I do:

```
myfile = h5py.File("/path_to_the_directory/merged_images.hdf5", 'w')
myfile['0.000'] = h5py.ExternalLink("img_000.hdf5", "/path_to_the_directory/images")
myfile['0.001'] = h5py.ExternalLink("img_001.hdf5", "/path_to_the_directory/images")
myfile.flush()
```

Then I try to read it with:

```
myfile = h5py.File("/path_to_the_directory/merged_images.hdf5", 'r')
keys = list(myfile.keys())
print(keys)
print(list(myfile[keys[0]]))
```

The line `print(keys)` gives me `['0.000', '0.001']`. So, I believe the file's structure is okay.

And the next lines gives me an exception:
 `KeyError: "Unable to open object (unable to open external file, external link file name = 'img_000.hdf5')"`

Am I doing something wrong? The documentation is pretty poor and I haven
t found a relevant use-case there.

Comment: Were your problems resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing up paths. It is important to distinguish between two types of paths:

- File path (the location on your hard drive).
- Dataset path: this path is internal to the HDF5-file, and does not depend on where you store the file.

The syntax of `h5py.ExternalLink`, as mentioned in [the documentation](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/group.html?highlight=ExternalLink#external-links), is:

```
myfile['/path/of/link'] = h5py.ExternalLink('/path/to/file.hdf5', '/path/to/dataset')
```

> Thereby I would like to encourage you to use a [relative file path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29) for the `ExternalLink`. If you do that, then everything will continue to work even if you move the collection of files to a new location on your hard drive (or give them to somebody else).

With the correct paths, your example works, as shown below.

*Note that, to illustrate my remark about relative file paths, I have made all paths of the datasets absolute (these are only internal to the file, and do not depend on where the file is stored on the hard drive) while I kept the **file paths relative***.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

myfile = h5py.File('test_a.hdf5', 'w')
myfile['/path/to/data'] = np.array([0,1,2])
myfile.close()

myfile = h5py.File('test_b.hdf5', 'w')
myfile['/path/to/data'] = np.array([3,4,5])
myfile.close()

myfile = h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'w')
myfile['/a'] = h5py.ExternalLink('test_a.hdf5', '/path/to/data')
myfile['/b'] = h5py.ExternalLink('test_b.hdf5', '/path/to/data')
myfile.close()

myfile = h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'r')
keys = list(myfile.keys())
print(keys)
print(list(myfile[keys[0]]))
print(list(myfile[keys[1]]))
myfile.close()
```

Prints (as expected):

```
['a', 'b']
[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
```